# Linq with Unity - Select One from Many

Tags: unity, c#, .net, linq

I'm using Linq to select the objects closest to the player that have the usable tag thusly:

```
GameObject[] usables = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Usable")
    .Where(t => Vector3.Distance(t.transform.position, playerT.position) < useDistance)
    .ToArray();
```

This works as I intended, but I'd like to further narrow it down to the closest object in that array so the Linq query returns only the single closest GO.  Linq is, however, a serious weak spot for me.  Any thoughts on how that would look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post on ["How to use linq to find the minimum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736236/how-to-use-linq-to-find-the-minimum) will give you some ideas on this. The `MinBy` extension method in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.github.io/) is likely your best bet, as there isn't a built-in method for what you want to do in `System.Linq`.

Doing this in pure LINQ is possible with LINQ methods like `Aggregate` or even `OrderBy` to sort, but I think it is likely to be a bit clunky or not performant compared to non-pure LINQ code.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736385/5170571) shows how to use `Aggregate` to accomplish finding the minimum item. For example, if you really wanted to use LINQ for this:

```
var usables = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Usable");
var closestUsable = usables.Aggregate((minItem, nextItem) => Vector3.Distance(minItem.transform.position, playerT.position) < Vector3.Distance(nextItem.transform.position, playerT.position) ? minItem : nextItem)
// check if (closestUsable < useDistance), or add another `Where` method to keep it LINQ
```

However, this involves calling `Vector3.Distance` more often than necessary and it is also not very readable.

EDIT: This is how this would look like with `OrderBy` which is more readable, but runs in O(n log n) time due to the sorting:

```
    GameObject closestUsable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Usable")
        .OrderBy(t => Vector3.Distance(t.transform.position, playerT.position))
        .Where(t => Vector3.Distance(t.transform.position, playerT.position) < useDistance)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```